# Yum install on CentOS 6.2

Tags: php, centos, yum

I can't install any php extension

Epel repository enabled

Yum is updated

**yum repolist** shows

```
repo id                                repo name                                                                      status
base                                   CentOS-6 - Base                                                                  5,932+362
epel                                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                 5,867+1,143
extras                                 CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                        4
updates                                CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                  334+83
repolist: 12,137
```

**yum install php-soap** 
or 
**yum --enablerepo=epel install php-soap** output:

```
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.dedipower.com
 * epel: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirrors.dedipower.com
 * updates: mirror.as29550.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php-soap available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**epel.repo** content

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

**UPD**

**yum search php** :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                             |  13 kB     00:00
 * base: mirrors.dedipower.com
 * epel: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirrors.dedipower.com
 * updates: mirror.as29550.net
======================================================= N/S Matched: php ========================================================
cups-php.x86_64 : Common Unix Printing System - php module
eclipse-phpeclipse.noarch : PHP Eclipse plugin
graphviz-php.x86_64 : PHP extension for graphviz
nntpgrab-php.x86_64 : PHP module which allows PHP scripts to communicate with NNTPGrab
rrdtool-php.x86_64 : PHP RRDtool bindings
uuid-php.x86_64 : PHP support for Universally Unique Identifier library
lighttpd-fastcgi.x86_64 : FastCGI module and spawning helper for lighttpd and PHP configuration
limph.noarch : A PHP5-compatible network host/service poller with web interface
tiquit.noarch : A PHP5-compatible help desk incident tracking/knowledgebase system

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

**UPD2**
Solved.
Thanks all.
Problem was **explude = php.*** in my **yum.conf**

Comment: Are you behind the proxy, and please paste error also

Comment: can you do a `yum search php` and see if the soap (or any other rpm for that matter) exists?

Comment: no, i am not behind the proxy

Comment: can attache error when you run yum install XXX -y

Comment: Please don't add your answer to the question or "[Solved]" to the title. I know [it's suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114314/should-we-really-be-suggesting-that-people-put-the-answer-in-the-question) but it's not how Stack Exchange really works. Add your solution **as an answer** when you can.